# Trouble rendering images uploaded with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm building a basic Rails 4 application, and seem to have hit a frustrating snag. I've been following the [CarrierWave Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads), and while I'm able to get images to show up on /image/show.html.erb, I've had some difficulties with getting any of the images I've uploaded to display in the gallery each image is associated with.

The strange thing is, there aren't any errors logged. The page loads without any Rails errors coming up in the page or the terminal; the only way I know something is wrong is that the div that images are supposed to appear in doesn't show up at all.

I'm really stumped about this. If you look, the .images div in the show action for galleries renders, but absolutely none of the sub-elements render at all. What am I doing wrong?

[Source code here](https://github.com/DeadSuperHero/DeadSuperHero)

**app/models/image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**app/models/gallery.rb**

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
end
```

**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
   end


end
```

**apps/views/images/show.html.erb**
Below, we can see that images can be rendered without issue, as this is a view for their own respective controller.

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @image.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @image.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Image:</strong>
  <%= image_tag @image.image_url.to_s %>
</p>
```

**/apps/views/galleries/show.html.erb**
This is where everything gets tricky. First off, no matter what I change within the images div, everything within it seems to come up blank regardless. I've tried changing the "for image in @gallery.images" bit several times, but to no avail.

```
<div id="images">
  <% for image in @gallery.images %>
    <div class="image">
      <%= image_tag image.image_url(:thumb) %>
      <%= image.description %>
      <div class="name"><%= image.title %></div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= link_to "edit", edit_image_path(image) %> |
        <%= link_to "remove", image, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Add a Painting", new_image_path(:gallery_id => @gallery) %> |
  <%= link_to "Remove Gallery", @gallery, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> |
  <%= link_to "View Galleries", galleries_path %>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you actually setting the `gallery_id` when you create an image?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, though. I've updated my question to further reflect this. :)

Comment: May we see your ImageUploader please?

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated the original question to include it.

Comment: Where are you setting the galery_id? I can't find it.

Comment: The gallery_id is set on the link for creating a new image. So, <%= link_to "Add a Painting", new_image_path(:gallery_id => @gallery) %>

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the gallery and the image. One option is to pass the gallery_id to the new action like you do now, set it in the controller on the new image, add a hidden field to transport it to the create action and whitelist the parameter there.

The other option is to nest the image routes into the gallery routes like so:

```
resources :galleries do
  resources :images
end
```

This will create URLs like `/galleries/123/images/234` and `galleries/1233/images/new`. You create links to these page for example with `edit_galleries_image_path(@gallery, @image)`. Again you would need to set the correct `gallery_id` in `images#new` on the new image but that should then let `form_for` generate the right path to the create action where you then have the `gallery_id` parameter available. Going this way `rake routes` should come in as a handy tool.

Comment: Nesting the images in galleries seems like the way to go. However, at the moment I'm getting `undefined method 'images_path'`, so my form partial looks like it will need to somehow be tweaked. On the bright side, the routing looks a lot nicer!